# Asymptotic expansion for $\int e^{i\lambda x^2}e^{-x^2}x^j\text{d}x$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, asymptotics, complex-integration, oscillatory-integral

I want to prove Theorem 2.5 on page 9 from these [lecture notes](https://www.math.sciences.univ-nantes.fr/%7Evitturi/lecture_notes/oscillatory_integrals_lecture_notes.pdf#equation.2.1) by following the guidelines provided in Exercise 13 on page 18. Using complex integration one shows that
\begin{equation}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i\lambda x^2}e^{-x^2}x^m\text{d}x=(1-i\lambda)^{-\frac{m+1}{2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-x^2}x^m \text{d}x=\lambda^{-\frac{m+1}{2}}\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}-i\right)^{-\frac{m+1}{2}}\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{-x^2}x^j \text{d}x\;\;\;\;\;(1)\end{equation}
Then the hint is to write $$\left(z-i\right)^{-\frac{m+1}{2}}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}c_{k}^{(m)}z^{k}$$ as a power series for $|z|<1$ and set $z=\frac{1}{\lambda}$. Until here I think I understand all steps but what I don't see is how to conclude
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^{i\lambda x^2}e^{-x^2}x^m\text{d}x-\lambda^{-1/2}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}a_j\lambda^{-j/2}=\mathcal{O}(\lambda^{-N/2})$$
for suitable coefficients $a_j$ and $N\in\mathbb{N}$.

Edit: Solved thanks to advice in the comments. Using $\left(\frac{1}{\lambda}-i\right)^{-\frac{m+1}{2}}=\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}c_k^{(m)}\lambda^{-k}+\mathcal{O}(\lambda^{-N})$ we get that the right side of (1) euqals (for convenience I set $\hat{c}_j=\int e^{-x^2}x^j \text{d}x$)
$$\hat{c}_j\lambda^{-\frac{m+1}{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}c_k^{(m)}\lambda^{-k}+\mathcal{O}(\lambda^{-N-\frac{m+1}{2}})=\hat{c}_j\lambda^{-\frac{1}{2}}\sum_{k=1}^{N-1}c_k^{(m)}\lambda^{-\frac{2k+m}{2}}+\mathcal{O}(\lambda^{-N-\frac{m+1}{2}})$$
Rename the coefficients and we are done.

Comment: Use the fact that $
(z - i)^{ - \frac{{m + 1}}{2}}  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^{N - 1} {c_k^{(m)} z^k }  + \mathcal{O}(z^N )
$ near $z=0$, which follows from Taylor's theorem.

Comment: Yes I already thought about that but I dont see how it helps because if you set $\lambda=1/z$ you would have $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}c_k^{(m)}\lambda^{-k}$ but you want something like $\sum_{k=0}^{N-1}\widetilde{c}_k\lambda^{-k/2}$.

Comment: Do not forget about the multiplication by $\lambda^{-m/2}$. The first several (depending on $m$) coefficients $a_j$ will be zero.

Comment: I edited my question, is this what you mean?

Comment: Yes, now you just have to re-name things.